# Why is Worf in The Undiscovered Country?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng, star-trek-tos

After watching *The Undiscovered Country* I noticed that the advocate for Kirk and Bones during their trial is none other than Michael Dorn, a.k.a. Worf.  During the trial I believe they even call the advocate Worf by name.

How can this be when Worf is alive and aboard the Enterprise D almost 70 years later? Is there any in-universe explanation for this, or any outside universe explanation for why Michael Dorn is in Undiscovered Country?

Comment: Do you know the life span of a Klingon?

Comment: It’s definitely not Worf from The Next Generation, because he was raised as a child by human parents on earth.

Comment: Or so he claims.

Comment: Similar question would be why is the _President of the Federation_ working as helmsman on ... the Saratoga (I believe that was the name) in The Voyage Back?

Comment: ... or why Tuvok appears in at least four different roles under different names :p

Comment: @Damon Hahaha..

Comment: Changlings, all of them

Comment: Maybe if they stopped trying to time travel so much, this would not hapen.

Comment: @Damon: How do you get that idea about the President of the Federation and the Saratoga helmsman? They just happen to belong to the [same species](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Efrosian), but they were played by different actors.

Comment: @Plutor His claims are backed up by his adoptive parents and brother. It would be a remarkably elaborate ruse if it weren't true; seems unlikely.

Comment: Kinda feel like "What, can't the same actor play different roles?" is a pretty cheap rationalization when  taking about Michael Dorn and Star Trek.

Answer (score 76):

According to [Memory Alpha](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Michael_Dorn);

> Between the fourth and fifth seasons of Star Trek: The Next
>   Generation, Dorn played **Colonel Worf** in Star Trek VI: The Undiscovered
>   Country. Although the relationship was not stated on screen, the
>   filmmakers' intention was that the Star Trek VI character was the
>   grandfather of the Next Generation character. (Star Trek Encyclopedia)

In an [interview with Michael Dorn](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lLtyi5r7vp0#t=1h20m32s) (seen at 1h20m32s) during *The Undiscovered Country* segment of the [25th Anniversary Special](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Star_Trek_25th_Anniversary_Special) he states this relationship.

Comment: His grandpa? Huh..

Comment: @user931 This is not very surprising. In real life I look almost identical to one of my great-grandfathers.

Answer (score 32):

Appearences to the contrary (after all it's even the same actor) this is a  [different Worf than in TNG](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Worf_%28Colonel%29):

> Although it was never confirmed on screen, publicity materials for
>   Star Trek VI indicated that Colonel Worf was intended to be the
>   grandfather of his Next Generation namesake, and the father of Mogh.

Comment: Same actor, yes, but different makeup. The forehead ridges are similar, but definitely not equal as on TNG's Worf. Compare [this](http://vignette2.wikia.nocookie.net/memoryalpha/images/e/e6/ColonelWorf.jpg/revision/latest?cb=20051115201222&path-prefix=nl) and [this](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/it/1/12/Tenente_Worf_-_Star_Trek_TNG.jpg), for example.